# Reinit javascript function when change view in vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js

I am kinda new in vue.js

I have a laravel app with vue.js. When hp is loading script also loading all elements are initialised (owl carousel, rev slider etc), but when i click other route contact or about and come back to hp the sliders or other related to js doesnt load .

```
routes.js
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Home from './components/views/Home.vue';
import About from './components/views/About.vue';
import Contact from './components/views/Contact.vue';


let routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/about', component: About },
    { path: '/contact', component: Contact },
    { path: '/notes', component: Notes }
];

export default new VueRouter({
    routes,
    linkActiveClass: 'active'
});
```

and `app.js`

```
import router from './routes';

import './components';

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

Is there a way to run the functions to load carousels etc each time i change view ?

Comment: Where and how are they being loaded now?

Comment: its loaded as <script src="static/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script> into  master.blade

Comment: Ok - Normally you would put that code inside vue components instead of loading it separately.

Answer (score 0):

On mounted trigger you can add your custom js for each component

```
<script>
    export default {
        mounted () {

        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone stumbles upon this and still looking for a way to do it, this is how I managed to do this. wrap the `<route-view/>` in a `<transition>` which you can control with css and call a method on enter which calls the function you want.
this will call the function as soon as the component is loaded in the DOM on every route change

```
<transition name="slide" v-on:enter="reInitJS">
   <router-view></router-view>
</transition>

<script>
//import the wanted function
import {init} from './main';
export default {
  name: 'App', 
  methods: {
    reInitJS(){
    //call the function
      init(); 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```